Looking for a real game that ends with queen sacrifice and discovered check with a pawn
In the novel that I am writing, I would like to feature a chess game between two amateur players. Maybe their ELO rating would be about 1200. I want to create a position where, for the player who is about to play...

The queen is trapped
The queen is attacked
A queen sacrifice can lead to mate in 1 or 2 moves
In one of the final moves, a pawn moves to give a discovered check.

I have created such a position, but it does not come from a real game.
White: fxg4 (blunder)
Black to play:
[Fen "1k1r4/1b3p2/1p1p1B1r/p1p4p/5qP1/N2QN3/P1B1n1PP/1R3R1K b - - 0 1"]
[Title ""]
[StartFlipped "0"]

FEN
1k1r4/1b3p2/1p1p1B1r/p1p4p/5qP1/N2QN3/P1B1n1PP/1R3R1K b - - 0 1
Link on Lichess
I would be very grateful to anyone who can provide a link or a PGN for a game that ends in the way I have described.

For the purposes of my story, the players should not have a high level, as you can tell from White's blunder. Black is a twelve-year-old playing against his mother, and he believes that he has lost the game because he cannot save his queen. Another twelve-year-old friend points out the queen sacrifice and the unassuming pawn move. This friend is a better player, but not an expert.
The game is just a minor incident, and will not be treated in detail, so that readers who don't play chess don't feel lost. However, I feel that I would be cheating real players if I used a fake position.

However, I feel that I would be cheating real players if I used a fake position. -> there are many chess fictions that use on-purpose fabricated positions, and I have never heard of someone feeling cheated or offended by that.

Honestly, your position would be good enough already if you just gave black an equal number of minor pieces as white. It's a realistic position. For instance, remove the knight on a3 (which doesn't cover any crucial squares), and give black a knight on c8. There, black would be up 3 pawns before the "blunder," so that could be incorporated into the story. Or if you want material to be equal, don't give black a knight on c8.

Given that the "normal" game in a movie always goes like this: 5 plies in a row, every one capturing a piece and giving a check at the same time, the fifth move also delivering checkmate - I think that "sacrifice the queen to deliver mate in 1 or two" is a kind of "bland" requirement for a game.

"Another twelve-year-old friend points out the queen sacrifice and the unassuming pawn move"  And this is why kibitzing is prohibited...

Mother goes off to greet the parents of the friend, who have just arrived, assuming that she has won. This also explains the inattention that led to blunder: there are more pressing things to do.
